# Ini4j classpath no class

Tags: java, jar, ini4j

i am want create jar of my project using cmd line.

I am using `ini4j` libs. 
Everything compiles fine, but I do not know how to set the `-cp` to the library.

Compile:

```
javac -cp ".;lib/ini4j-0.5.2.jar;ini4j-0.5.2-jdk14.jar;lib/ini4j-0.5.2-jdk14.jar" gui_Frame/*.java
```

Create jar:

```
echo Main-class: gui_Frame/MainApp > manifest.txt
jar cvfm GVE.jar manifest.txt gui_Frame/*
```

But, if i want start `java -jar GVE.jar` i get following error:

```
Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/ini4j/wini
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the same classpath when running java as you did when compiling.

Or bundle all the necessary class files in one JAR.

==EDIT==

Try this:

```
java -cp "GVE.jar;.;lib/ini4j-0.5.2.jar" gui_Frame.MainApp
```

Comment: `java ".;lib/ini4j-0.5.2.jar;ini4j-0.5.2-jdk14.jar;lib/ini4j-0.5.2-jdk14.jar" -jar GVE.jar` not working.